# In AsyncCallback trying to call End Invoke The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I am calling a method using a delegate begin invoke.  When it gets into the AsyncCallback method, I am trying to retrieve the result of the function using EndInvoke but am getting the error

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

My call back method looks like this:

```
Private Sub GenerateCallback(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
    Dim html As String = generateDelegate.EndInvoke(result) -- Error occurs here
    Dispatcher.Invoke(Function(value As String) CurrentWebResults.DocumentText = value, html)
End Sub
```

I tried using a Dispatch.Invoke which did not fix the problem and doesn't seem to make sense since neither the variable "html" nor the generateDelegate should be on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EndInvoke() will *rethrow* any exception that was raised on the delegate's target method.  Which most certainly runs on a worker thread when you use a delegate's BeginInvoke() method.  Clearly that method is accessing a thread-unsafe object, the kind that requires Dispatcher.Invoke().

If you have no idea which it might be then use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  The debugger will now stop at the statement that raised this exception.  Favor the Task class or async/await.

Comment: My goal is to allow the UI to remain active while a potentially long running process executes.  I've been able to get it to execute now but the UI remains unresponsive until the Callback is reached.  Would switching to Tasks be viable solution and if so would it fix the UI problem?

Comment: I suppose I need to either create a new question or read up more on how to create a responsive UI during long processes in WPF.